# How to assign an ID to a button in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I have a table with some content and Edit button. This is the code which produces a datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var params = {};
    callFunction("getAgentList", params,
        function(bSuccess, res) {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                data: res,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "ID" },
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "AltName1" },
                    { "data": "AltName2" },
                    { "data": "AltName3" },
                    { "data": "AltName4" },
                    { "data": "AltName5" },
                    { "data": "AltName6" },
                    { "data": "AltName7" },
                    { "data": "AltName8" },
                    { "data": "AltName9" },
                    { "data": "AltName10" },
                    {
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": '<button class="btn btn-warning" id='+res+' onclick="edit(this)">Edit</button>'
                    },
                ],
                "order": [
                    [1, 'asc']
                ]
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Each row should have an edit button for editing that specified row. For this I need an ID which I have in `res` JSON. But I am not sure how to get the ID for each of the edit buttons?

Right now if I put only `res` I get Object or with `res.ID` it is undefined. Which makes sense because I need to loop over the array...

Anyone?

**EDIT**

This is the `res` JSON:

```
{ AltName1: "Test1", AltName10: "", AltName2: "Test1Alt", AltName3: "Test1", AltName4: "Test1", ID: "1" }
{ AltName1: "Test2", AltName10: "", AltName2: "", AltName3: "", AltName4: "", ID: "2" }
```

If I set the id as `<button class="btn btn-warning" id='+res[0].ID+' onclick="edit(this)">Edit</button>`

Then all buttons have the same ID.

Comment: have you try to dump the result of `res` using `console.log`?

Comment: Yes. The JSON is not the problem. The problem is how to assign the ID to each of their respective Edit buttons.

Comment: i just want to know the result. maybe there is an ID in the `res`

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change all the first letters to lowercase in JavaScript then use the render function of datatable:

```
 { "targets": 0, "data": 'iD' },
{ "targets": 1, "data": 'name' },
{ "targets": 2, "data": 'altName1' },
{ "targets": 3, "data": 'altName2' },
{ "targets": 4, "data": 'altName3' },
{ "targets": 5, "data": 'altName4' },
{ .... },
{
    "targets": 6,
    "data": 'iD',
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return '<button class="btn btn-warning" id='+data+' onclick="edit(this)">Edit</button>'
    }
}
```

In the render function you can access the ID with different ways :
1 : "data" : 'iD' then you use data (as I did)
2 : "data" : 'anything you want' then you use : row.iD

Also note please that  you need to add a prefix before the ID to avoid repeated Id's (I always do that)

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. You should link to the docs -> https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render **but be aware** that `id`'s *not* should start with a number, `id="3"` is not valid HTML. So refer to the ID with an attribute like `data-id="'+data+'"` instead....

Comment: Great! However it works with upperCase letters too. :/

Answer (score -1):

just try this

```
"defaultContent": '<button class="btn btn-warning" id='+ID+' onclick="edit('+ID+')">Edit</button>'
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ID is not defined

Comment: But where does `ID` come from ...?  The problem is, that you not have access to the row content in `defaultContent`.

Comment: It comes from the JSON which I get when I call the `getAgentList` URL.